# render another controller action and filling form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-5.1, ruby-on-rails-5

when i submit a form if it has some errors we can do something like this:

```
def create
  @proposal = Proposal.new(proposal_params)
  if @proposal.save
    redirect_to @proposal
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

but my form is submitting to another controllers action

how can i have the same results rendering the :new action of other controller passing the id of the previous to show the form errors and presenting the form with the giving text.

cause if i do:

```
def create
  @proposal = Proposal.new(proposal_params)
  if @proposal.save
    redirect_to @proposal
  else
    redirect_to other_controller_path(@user)
  end
end
```

the validations errors will not show up

Comment: What do you mean by "passing the id of the previous..." if the previous proposal instance `@proposal` was not created because of errors, there's no id generated.  Best is if you just pass `@proposal` and use it in the rendered form of the other controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass @proposal.errors to the redirect in flash:

`redirect_to other_controller_path(@user), notice: @proposal.errors` or something along those lines, depending on how you have your errors set up in your app.